# Powershell space in string variable fails when passed to command

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add multiple AppRoles to an Application in Azure AD. With this script I can list the roles I need:

```
$apiAppRoles = az ad app list --app-id $apiId --query '[0].appRoles' `
    | ConvertFrom-Json `
    | Where-Object {$_.value -in "role1", "role2"} `
```

I then want to pass these roles as the `$permissions` variable in the following command:

```
az ad app permission add `
    --id $appId `
    --api $apiId `
    --api-permissions $permissions
```

The `--api-permissions` parameter is defined as *Space-separated list of {id}={type}*. So I build up the string variable:

```
$test = "$($apiAppRoles[0].id)=Role $($apiAppRoles[1].id)=Role"
```

and pass it into the command.

This gives me the following error:

```
Usage error: Please provide both permission id and type, such as `--api-permissions e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d=Scope`
```

However, if I put the value of my `$permissions` variable in the command and run it literally, it does work (dummy GUIDs):

```
az ad app permission add `
    --id $appId `
    --api $apiId `
    --api-permissions 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role
```

If I run the script with just one AppRole it also works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I can’t test right now, but from memory I think Powershell is probably wrapping the entire ```$permissions``` string I quotes, so ```--api-permissions “00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role”``` I *think* you have to pass the two strings as an array instead - ```$permissions = @( "$($apiAppRoles[0].id)=Role”, “$($apiAppRoles[1].id)=Role" )```…

Comment: I agree with mclayton.  You first need to request a token (cookie) which is working.  Than need to include the cookie with each request.  You second request does not include the token.

Comment: @mclayton yep, that did it. I added `| ForEach-Object {"$($_.id)=Role"}` and passed that into the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answer expanded from comments ^^^)

PowerShell is wrapping the entire `$permissions` string in quotes because it contains a space character, so the command it's executing is:

```
az ad app permission add --id myid --api myapi --api-permissions "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role"
```

Note how the *entire* `-api-permissions` parameter value is a single string enclosed in double quotes, which is not what you want :-(.

To fix this, you can initialise the `$permissions` veriable as an *array* of strings like this:

```
PS> $permissions = @(
    "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role",
    "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role"
);

PS> az ad app permission add --id myid --api myapi --api-permissions $permissions
```

and PowerShell will stringify them as individual values which will invoke this:

```
az ad app permission add --id myid --api myapi --api-permissions 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role
```

which is what you actually want :-).

---

### Bonus Round

For future reference there's a third-party utility called **EchoArgs** which is super-useful when troubleshooting similar issues - it basically echoes the command line that was invoked so you can see what PowerShell is doing.

This is what happens with your literal command (note it's invoking `echoargs.exe` instead of `az.exe`):

```
PS> & "c:\src\so\echoargs.exe" ad app permission add `
    --id myid `
    --api myapi `
    --api-permissions 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role

Arg 0 is <ad>
Arg 1 is <app>
Arg 2 is <permission>
Arg 3 is <add>
Arg 4 is <--id>
Arg 5 is <myid>
Arg 6 is <--api>
Arg 7 is <myapi>
Arg 8 is <--api-permissions>
Arg 9 is <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role>
Arg 10 is <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role>

Command line:
"C:\src\so\echoargs.exe" ad app permission add --id myid --api myapi --api-permissions 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role
```

and then with `$permissions` as a single string variable:

```
PS> $permissions = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role"

PS> & "c:\src\so\echoargs.exe" ad app permission add `
    --id myid `
    --api myapi `
    --api-permissions $permissions

Arg 0 is <ad>
Arg 1 is <app>
Arg 2 is <permission>
Arg 3 is <add>
Arg 4 is <--id>
Arg 5 is <myid>
Arg 6 is <--api>
Arg 7 is <myapi>
Arg 8 is <--api-permissions>
Arg 9 is <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role>

Command line:
"C:\src\so\echoargs.exe" ad app permission add --id myid --api myapi --api-permissions "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role"
```

and finally with `$permissions` as an array variable:

```
PS> $permissions = @(
    "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role",
    "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role"
);

PS> & "c:\src\so\echoargs.exe" ad app permission add `
    --id myid `
    --api myapi `
    --api-permissions $permissions

Arg 0 is <ad>
Arg 1 is <app>
Arg 2 is <permission>
Arg 3 is <add>
Arg 4 is <--id>
Arg 5 is <myid>
Arg 6 is <--api>
Arg 7 is <myapi>
Arg 8 is <--api-permissions>
Arg 9 is <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role>
Arg 10 is <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role>

Command line:
"C:\src\so\echoargs.exe" ad app permission add --id myid --api myapi --api-permissions 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001=Role 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002=Role
```